# How hard would it be for me to transfer a powerdot presentation to beamer?

Tags: beamer, powerdot

I have been enjoying learning to use Powerdot, except when it comes to images. I have EPS files that end up the wrong way round and I have decided just to give it up. I have a one-off presentation to give and time is tight.
I was thinking about switching to Powerpoint, but I will have wasted time making slides in Latex. Is Beamer any better for images and just how much will the powerdot code suffice if I just used beamer? Here is an example;

```
\begin{slide}

\begin{tikzpicture}

%\path[use as bounding box] (-11,-300) rectangle (1.0,4.5);
\node[inner sep=0pt] at (-0.8,4.1)
{\includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth]{EjecCon-2pi3/velCon-12400-Ejec-2pi3.eps}};
\node[inner sep=0pt] at (0.15,8.04)
{\includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth]{EjecCon-2pi3/velCon-14800-Ejec-2pi3.eps}};
\node[inner sep=0pt] at (-9.75,6.2)
{\includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth]{EjecCon-2pi3/velCon-19600-Ejec-2pi3.eps}};
\node[inner sep=0pt] at (-6.7,2.7)
{\includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth]{EjecCon-2pi3/velCon-22000-Ejec-2pi3.eps}};


\draw[orange, thick] (-8,5) node (v14) {} .. controls (-8,8) and (-5,8) .. (-4,8) node (v17) {};
\draw[orange, thick] (-7.88,5) node (v15) {} .. controls (-7.95,7.76) and (-4.9,7.8) .. (-4,7.8) node (v18) {};

%ARROW
\node (v19) at (-4,8.2) {};
\node (v20) at (-3.7,7.9) {};
\node (v21) at (-4,7.6) {};

\draw[orange, thick]  plot[tension=.7] coordinates {(v17) (v19) (v20) (v21) (v18)};

\draw[orange]  (v17) edge node[above] {\textbf{increasing $\alpha$}} (v19);
\node[inner sep=0pt, orange] at (-7.21,4.76) {\textbf{ejection maximum}};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{slide}
```

Comment: A third option (which might be faster) would be to solve your Powerdot problem. Can you post a minimal example that shows what you mean by an EPS image ending up the wrong way round?

Comment: I think it's something to do with the slides being in landscape mode. 
I couldn't get the bounding box right either.

Comment: Thanks for adding the code. Can you make it a complete compilable document instead of a code fragment. Also, does the problem arise with *any* `.eps` file? (Because we can't test with your actual files.)

Comment: Now I'm confused. This isn't a Powerdot document at all. But the issue seems to me to be more based on the fact that you are specifying all your node coordinates manually. It would be preferable to use the TikZ `positioning` library to position the nodes relative to one another I think.  Also it's not really clear what problem the code poses for you.  What do you want the layout to look like?